# Android maven using wrong java version

Tags: android, android-maven-plugin

I'm compiling my Android project against Android V2.2.1, I'm using an Android dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Everything compiles fine and libraries that were introduced in later versions (Nfc related stuff for example) are not available and that's fine.

The problem arises when I'm using pure java methods like String.isEmpty which were introduced only in V2.3+, for some reason Maven doesn't fail with "cannot find symbol" but the compilation passes, it only fails on the device that runs version 2.2.

My android-maven-plugin conf:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml
        </androidManifestFile>
        <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
        <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
        <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native
        </nativeLibrariesDirectory>
        <sdk>
            <platform>8</platform>
        </sdk>
        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>

</plugin>
```

How can I make sure that the compile will fail ?

Comment: 1. How do you build the fault apk, via Eclipse or Maven connamd-line? 2. What API version do you define in project.properties?

Comment: Via eclipse, but with the maven plugin.
# Project target.
target=android-8

Comment: I tried through the command line now and it compiles successfully.

Comment: Not solved, the problem is that it compiles successfully, I want it to fail.

Comment: Set project.properties to use android-9 should fail the build, give it a try and see if works.

Comment: According to the [plugin documentation](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/apk-mojo.html#sdk), set <sdk> should work. I can't remember if this happened in older version of android-maven-plugin. Try to raise a issue at [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/list).

Comment: @Efi MK: I'm having this same problem (see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250352/base-java-classes-still-in-the-classpath-during-maven-android-build). Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the original android jar from the Sdk by deploying it to your repository or repository server using the Maven Android SDK Deployer. That might work.