# Base java classes still in the classpath during maven android build

Tags: android, maven, classpath

I'm having a rather strange problem caused by both the facts that the android java implementation differs from the sun java implementation and that the base java classes are still included in the classpath (all the way at the end) during a maven build of an android project. I think the solution is to not have the java classes on the classpath, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Basically, there is a class called AbstractExecutorService in java.util.concurrent (in both android and java). The java class contains a couple methods called newTaskFor which I'd like to use in android, but the android implementation doesn't have them. No problem, I'll just implement them (with a few changes such as using Future instead of RunnableFuture). This works fine in ant (the build tool we are migrating away from).

The problem is that when maven tries to compile my class (which extends AbstractExecutorService), instead of just adding my methods to the android implementation when it doesn't find them, it continues down the classpath, finds the java methods and complains that the return types don't match. Ideally I don't think the java classes should even be available during an android build, since all they can do is cause you to think you can run methods which you really can't, but currently you can run all sorts of java methods not available in android and it will compile fine (in maven).

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions for this? Anyone run into something similar?

**Edit: here is the relevant part of the pom (omitted repositories and such):**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b5</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-with-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.byteman</groupId>
        <artifactId>byteman-bmunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>140</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>conf</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*-service.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/schema</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
           <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
           <includes>
              <include>INSTALL.html</include>
              <include>LICENSE</include>
              <include>README</include>
           </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
          <includes>
             <include>licenses/thirdparty*</include>
          </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>stuff/stuff/util/JUnitXMLReporter.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.7</version>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                   <sources>
                      <source>target/generated-sources</source>
                   </sources>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
             <execution>
                <id>add-test-source</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                   <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                </goals>
             </execution>
          </executions>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                  <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <echo>Precompiling magic ids and protocol ids</echo>    
                        <xslt in="conf/stuff.xml" out="target/generated-sources/stuff/stuff/ClassMagicEncoding.java"
                            style="conf/stuff.xslt">
                            <param name="type" expression="Magic"/>
                        </xslt>
                        <xslt in="conf/stuff.xml" out="target/generated-sources/stuff/stuff/ClassProtocolEncoding.java"
                            style="conf/stuff.xslt">
                            <param name="type" expression="Protocol"/>
                        </xslt>
                    </tasks>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                            <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
                            <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/schema" failonerror="false"/>
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/schema"/>
                            <java classname="stuff.stuff.util.XMLSchemaGenerator">
                                <classpath>
                                    <pathelement path="${compile_classpath}"/>
                                    <pathelement path="${plugin_classpath}"/>
                                </classpath>
                                <arg line="-o ${project.build.directory}/schema"/>
                            </java>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <!-- prints the classpath to ensure correct jars are available -->
                <tasks>
                            <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                    <echo>rawr=${compile_classpath}</echo>
                    <echo>java.class.path=${java.class.path}</echo>
                    <echo>CLASSPATH=${env.CLASSPATH}</echo>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-antlr</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Main-Class>stuff.stuff.Version</Main-Class>
                    <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                    <Export-Package>
                        schema;version=${project.version},
                        ${project.groupId}.*;version=${project.version}
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>J2SE-1.6</Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                         <platform>8</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Edit2: Here is the compilation error I am getting.**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project mystuff: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/stuff/stuff/ExecutionService.java:[775,28] <T>newTaskFor(java.lang.Runnable,T) in stuff.ExecutionService cannot override <T>newTaskFor(java.lang.Runnable,T) in java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService; attempting to use incompatible return type
[ERROR] found   : java.util.concurrent.Future<T>
[ERROR] required: java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture<T>
[ERROR] /home/stuff/ExecutionService.java:[791,28] <T>newTaskFor(java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>) in stuff.ExecutionService cannot override <T>newTaskFor(java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>) in java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService; attempting to use incompatible return type
[ERROR] found   : java.util.concurrent.Future<T>
[ERROR] required: java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture<T>
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project mystuff: Compilation failure
```

Note: ExecutionService is the class which extends AbstractExecutorService. However, I want it to ONLY extend the android version and not the base java version. I even tried inserting stub methods of the newTaskFor's into the android version of AbstractExecutorService (in the thought that the compiler should then assume I am overriding those methods rather than the base java ones - although I should note that there is no @Override in the code) but it still didn't work.

No one asked for them but here are my method declarations:

```
protected <T> Future<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) 
{
//stuff
}

protected <T> Future<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) 
{
//stuff
{
```

My current theory is that it has something to do with the template types but I'm not really sure how to go about proving or fixing that.

**Edit 6/30:** I should also note that this is *not* new code. It is over a year old and has been compiling perfectly using ant since then. It has been a part of numerous stable releases. We are now in the process of migrating our build process to maven and thus I am trying to get this package set up to build properly.

Comment: Added. I realized I forgot to note that this is essentially (for all intents and purposes) a library project. Doesn't actually run on android, just provides stuff for apps to use.

Comment: Can you post the compile error in detail as well?

Comment: Yup, done. Also added some additional information.

Comment: I took a second look on you question, something doesn't feel quite right in your approach. Your modified android.jar is only used at compile time, the runtime framework.jar installed on the actual device/emulator never get it (unless you alter it somwhow). I am curious about how you did it with Ant, have you tried running the Ant-built apk on an arbitrary device (or emulator)? I don't think it is going to work, even though you follow Manfred's answer fix the classpath issue (which may let you pass the compilation).

Comment: The one which has been building in ant has been in use (production) for a long time. It works perfectly. Remember that it is just a library for android apps, so once the jar is compiled it will be relatively self-contained - when you reference the methods in the jar it shouldn't matter too much what THEY referenced at compile time, no?

Comment: Weird, no runtime exception probably because that line of code (where you use the modifiied API) doesn't get executed normally. Also better to check and see if the Ant-built apk really compiled against the modified android.jar. For more details about framework.jar, check out section <Compile time vs. Runtime for internal and hidden APIs> in [this blog post](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/).

Comment: The ant build isn't being built against a modified version of android, though. It works perfectly with normal android, because instead of searching the classpath and finding base java implementations at the end it searches the classpath, doesn't find the methods, and assumes (correctly) that I am defining new methods, not overriding predefined superclass methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Maven automatically has the Oracle JDK on the classpath and that the Android jar provides alternate implementations of these and they sometimes differ. At this stage I do not know if the Maven Compiler Plugin can be told to remove the JDK from its classpath and just use the dependencies on the classpath. That would imho solve the issue.

Please create an issue in the Android Maven Plugin issue tracker and potentially investigate by asking on the Maven user or dev list.

Comment: This is true - however, as I said in my comment below, I edited the android.jar with method declarations which are identical to my methods. The android.jar is the first item in the classpath. However, maven still picks up the java versions (which is the last item in the classpath) when trying to find the methods my methods implement. Any idea why this is?

Comment: It appears that (based on my research and testing) there is no way to remove the base java from the classpath. This essentially makes (hassle-free) android development impossible using maven, as you can never be sure which version it is using. Given all the trouble I've been having, I'm not sure how anyone uses maven for android builds... anyways, I'm going to accept your answer as there doesn't appear to be a solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you create an issue on the issue tracker .. I will ask on the maven dev list about this.

Comment: I asked now. Lets see what comes out of it.

Comment: I asked on the android-maven-plugin google groups page a bit ago. The person who responded told me how to fix it in eclipse, but when I told him "I don't use eclipse, I run from terminal" he stopped responding.

Comment: I use intellij and it should work there too but in any case.. it has to work on the command line first and foremost imho..

Comment: It works perfectly on ant, which has explicitly defined classpaths and so I simply don't tell the android ant builds about java libraries. Why maven doesn't have this option, I have no idea.

Comment: In the mailing list Maven Toolchains got suggested. That might work...  I just have no time to investigate at this stage. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html